# How do I configure the display on aarch64 VM with virt-install

Tags: qemu, arm64

I'm running this command:
`virt-install --virt-type kvm --name oracle --ram 4096 --location=/ssd/OracleLinux-R9-U3-aarch64-dvd.iso --disk path=/ssd/OracleLinux-R9-U3-aarch64-cloud.qcow2 --network=default --graphics=vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0 --noautoconsole`

It starts fine, but when I connect with vnc, I just get a black screen that says "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)."

I get nothing on the console, because for some reason, oracle linux doesn't provide serial console support in their images, so I'm trying to make an image with serial console support.

This is on an aarch64 arm Ubuntu 22.04 server. I probably need some kind of nvram, I just haven't found the magic words to use yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried what is above, as well as adding --arch=aarch64 --boot uefi

Answer (score 0):

So 2 updates.

1. The latest Oracle9 aarch64 image has console support, so this isn't needed
2. http://www.redfelineninja.org.uk/daniel/2018/02/running-an-iso-installer-image-for-arm64-aarch64-using-qemu-and-kvm/

Use this procedure to generate the EFI partition.